# Household mail merge (code golf)

Tags: code-golf

I wrote some mail merge code the other day and although it works I'm a turned off by the code. I'd like to see what it would look like in other languages.

So for the input the routine takes a list of contacts

```
Jim,Smith,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
Erica,Johnson,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
Abraham,Johnson,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
Marge,Simpson,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
Larry,Lyon,52560 Free Street,,Toronto,Ontario,Canada,M4B 1V7
Ted,Simpson,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
Raoul,Simpson,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
```

It will then merge lines with the same address and surname into one record. Assume the rows are unsorted). The code should also be flexible enough that fields can be supplied in any order (so it will need to take field indexes as parameters). For a family of two it concatenates both first name fields. For a family of three or more the first name is set to "the" and the lastname is set to "surname family".

```
Erica and Abraham,Johnson,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
Larry,Lyon,52560 Free Street,,Toronto,Ontario,Canada,M4B 1V7
The,Simpson Family,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
Jim,Smith,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
```

My C# implementation of this is:

```
var source = File.ReadAllLines(@"sample.csv").Select(l => l.Split(','));
var merged = HouseholdMerge(source, 0, 1, new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

public static IEnumerable<string[]> HouseholdMerge(IEnumerable<string[]> data, int fnIndex, int lnIndex, int[] groupIndexes)
{            
    Func<string[], string> groupby = fields => String.Join("", fields.Where((f, i) => groupIndexes.Contains(i)));

    var groups = data.OrderBy(groupby).GroupBy(groupby);

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        string[] result = group.First().ToArray();

        if (group.Count() == 2)
        {
            result[fnIndex] += " and " + group.ElementAt(1)[fnIndex];
        }
        else if (group.Count() > 2)
        {
            result[fnIndex] = "The";
            result[lnIndex] += " Family";
        }

        yield return result;
    }            
}
```

I don't like how I've had to do the groupby delegate. I'd like if C# had some way to convert a string expression to a delegate. e.g. Func groupby = f => "f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5] + f[1];" I have a feeling something like this can probably be done in Lisp or Python. I look forward to seeing nicer implementation in other languages.

Edit: Where did the community wiki checkbox go? Some mod please fix that.

Comment: But why `code-golf` this question? Read the [code golf guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions/24258#24258)

Comment: @Zaid, indeed, would be interesting to see this answered in a few languages without being golfed

Comment: I'm more interested in seeing it in other languages than having it code golfed but SO can have some over zealous mods that close questions that don't fit a very rigid format so I code-golf was the best way to keep it open.

Comment: I think there is a "shortest-code desired" or "most efficient solution desired" tag... something to that effect anyway.

Comment: Due to the removal of the CW checkbox for questions, it is time to get [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) off the ground so that we can move [code-golf] from Stack Overflow. *::gets out pom-poms and starts jumping around in drag::* **Rah! Rah! Ree!**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Golf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ruby — <s>181</s> 155

Name/surname indexes are in code:`a` and `b`. Input data is from ARGF.

```
a,b=0,1
[*$<].map{|i|i.strip.split ?,}.group_by{|i|i.rotate(a).drop 1}.map{|i,j|k,l,m=j
k[a]+=' and '+l[a]if l
(k[a]='The';k[b]+=' Family')if m
puts k*','}
```

Comment: Another hard one. Looks like ruby allows conditionals in an assignment "x = a if condition1 b if condition2"? The transpose function is nice. What does the asterisk after it do?

Comment: @Jacob, `String#*` == `String#join`

Comment: While I was sleeping, the longest solution and wrong solution (without indexes of name/surname) have got +1, and my was still 0. Hehe... Python-Ruby discrimination? )

Comment: odd, you had +2 when I looked earlier

Comment: @gnibbler, interesting ) I'm not angry, but it's funny.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.6.6 - 287 Characters

This assumes you can hard code a filename (named `i`). If you want to take input from command line, this goes up ~16 chars.

```
from itertools import*
for z,g in groupby(sorted([l.split(',')for l in open('i').readlines()],key=lambda x:x[1:]), lambda x:x[2:]):
 l=list(g);r=len(l);k=','.join(z);o=l[0]
 if r>2:print'The,'+o[1],"Family,"+k,
 elif r>1:print o[0],"and",l[1][0]+","+o[1]+","+k,
 else:print','.join(o),
```

---

**Output**

```
Erica and Abraham,Johnson,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
Larry,Lyon,52560 Free Street,,Toronto,Ontario,Canada,M4B 1V7
The,Simpson Family,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
Jim,Smith,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
```

I'm sure this could be improved upon, but it is getting late.

Comment: you can `import sys` and iterate over `sys.stdin` to take input from stdin

Comment: @gnibbler: Yep. That is the ~16 characters I'm talking about. :-)
There aren't any requirements (and the OP's code assumes sample.csv) so I will leave it until he specifies.

Comment: Nice, that's fairly readable. You've hardcoded indexes but I take it you could pass in a list something like this: lambda x:x[1,2,3,4,5] ?

Comment: @Jacob: Yeah. Both `lambda x:` can be changed to sort and group by different things.

Comment: you should sort by `key=lambda x:x[1:]` Otherwise people with the same last name but different addresses will break the grouping

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 178 chars

```
import sys
d={}
for x in sys.stdin:F,c,A=x.partition(',');d[A]=d.get(A,[])+[F]
print"".join([" and ".join(v)+c+A,"The"+c+A.replace(c,' Family,',1)][2<len(v)]for A,v in d.items())
```

Output

```
Jim,Smith,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
The,Simpson Family,6388 Lake City Way,,Burnaby,British Columbia,Canada,V5A 3A6
Larry,Lyon,52560 Free Street,,Toronto,Ontario,Canada,M4B 1V7
Erica and Abraham,Johnson,2681 Eagle Peak,,Bellevue,Washington,United States,98004
```

Comment: Thanks. That's going to take a while to decode. I can't tell where it determines if there are 1, 2, or 3+ people in the household.

Comment: @Jacob, `2<len(v)` 1 and 2 people are dealt with by the same code `" and ".join(v)+c+A`

Comment: Where are indexes of name/surname fields?

Answer (score 1):

### Python - not golfed

I'm not sure what the order of the rows should be if the indices are not 0 and 1 for the input file

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

class HouseHold(list):
    def __init__(self, fn_idx, ln_idx):
        self.fn_idx = fn_idx
        self.ln_idx = ln_idx

    def append(self, item):
        self.item = item
        list.append(self, item[self.fn_idx])

    def get_value(self):
        fn_idx = self.fn_idx
        ln_idx = self.ln_idx
        item = self.item
        addr = [j for i,j in enumerate(item) if i not in (fn_idx, ln_idx)]
        if len(self) < 3:
            fn, ln = " and ".join(self), item[ln_idx]
        else:
            fn, ln = "The", item[ln_idx]+" Family"
        return [fn, ln] + addr

def source(fname):
    with open(fname) as in_file:
        for item in csv.reader(in_file):
            yield item

def household_merge(src, fn_idx, ln_idx, groupby):
    res = defaultdict(lambda:HouseHold(fn_idx, ln_idx))
    for item in src:
        key = tuple(item[x] for x in groupby)
        res[key].append(item)
    return res.values()

data =  household_merge(source("sample.csv"), 0, 1, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
with open("result.csv", "w") as out_file:
    csv.writer(out_file).writerows(item.get_value() for item in data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the longer version. I like that tuples can be created from a list "tuple(item[x] for x in groupby)". Can you pass those to the sortby and groupby functions that Nick uses in his answer?

Comment: @Jacob, yes I could use `sorted` and `groupby` with that tuple as the key, but that would make the algorithm O(NlogN). This algorithm is O(N)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell - <strike>341</strike> 321

*(Changes as per comments).*

Unfortunately Haskell has no standard split function which makes this rather long.

Input to stdin, output on stdout.

```
import List
import Data.Ord
main=interact$unlines.e.lines
s[]=[]
s(',':x)=s x
s l@(x:y)=let(h,i)=break(==k)l in h:(s i)
t[]=[]
t x=tail x
h=head
m=map
k=','
e l=m(t.(>>=(k:)))$(m c$groupBy g$sortBy(comparing t)$m s l)
c(x:[])=x
c(x:y:[])=(h x++" and "++h y):t x
c x="The":((h$t$h x)++" Family"):(t$t$h x)
g a b=t a==t b
```

Comment: Use `List` instaed of `Data.List`. Use `t.concat.(>>=(',':))` instead of `concat.intersperse ","` if possible and declare `k=','` to save space. If not possible, at least remove the space after intersperse.

Comment: And, use an @-Pattern in `s(x:y)=let(h,i)=break(==',')(x:y)in h:(s i)` like `s l@(x:y)=h:(s i)where(h,i)=break(==',')l`

Comment: Hm... Don't know, whether it's against the rules, but you may also consider turning some of the ops into postfix functions (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#postfix-operators), it may save some typing for s, if you use pattern guards instead of simple patterns. I have to test this at home.

Comment: Cheers @FUZxxl - I'll make the changes you suggested tonight, and see how small we can get it.

Comment: PS: Change my `concatMap` to your `>>=` to safe some more. I forgot this obvious bounty.

Answer (score 0):

**Lua, 434 bytes**

```
x,y=1,2 s,p,r,a=string.gsub,pairs,io.read,{}for j,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in r('*a'):gmatch('('..('([^,]*),'):rep(7)..'([^,]*))\n')
do k=s(s(s(j,b,''),c,''),'[,%s]','')for l,m in p(a)do if not m.f and (m[y]:match(c) and m[9]==k) then z=1
if m.d then m[x]="The"m[y]=m[y]..' family'm.f=1 else m[x]=m[x].." and "..b m.d=1 end end end if not z then
a[#a+1]={b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k} end z=nil end for k,v in p(a)do v[9]=nil print(table.concat(v,','))end
```